# SQL Expression to Obtain Sum of All Payments on a Payment Schedule Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a `SELECT` statement to obtain the sum of all payments due from a table that contains payment schedule.  Fields include `PaymentID`, `PaymentAmount`, `NumberofMonths`.  So for example, there are three rows:

```
PaymentId | PaymentAmount | NumberofMonths
==========================================
1         |  500          |  12
2         |  2000         |  8
3         |  1000         |  6
```

The total amount of all payments due would be $28,000.00.  I'm a bit of a SQL/Oracle novice so I'm not sure how to get started with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregate function `SUM()` and multiply the `PaymentAmount` by the `NumberOfMonths`:

```
select sum(PaymentAmount * NumberofMonths) Total
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be580/2)